# document.getElementById doesnt work with "input id", how can I do it? [+Greasemonkey]

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I have this line on a website

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" value="" maxlength="20" class="shipBox" name="firstName" id="firstName">
```

and I want my greasemonkey to automatically fill this...

I'm trying this but had no success

```
document.getElementById("firstName").setAttribute("autocomplete", "on");
document.getElementById("firstName").value = "Bruno"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is basically the correct way.

The usual reaqson for this not working is a second element with the same ID somewhere in the document.

By the way, `setAttribute` is not the recommended way of setting an attribute in HTML, as I've been reminded today. A simple `...getElementById("firstName").autocomplete = 'on'` will do.

Comment: I've changed the autocomplete and still doesnt work... even only the autocomplete part doesnt work, and this is the only id with this name on the hole document